# What does Morley rank of a quotient group mean?

Tags: logic, model-theory

$ \DeclareMathOperator{\RM}{RM} $

I have a problem with understanding part b) of Exercise 6.6.23 in David Marker's "Model Theory: An Introduction": ($ \mathbb M $ is the monster model.)

> a) Suppose that $ \mathbb M $ is $ \omega $-stable, $ A , B \subseteq \mathbb M ^ n $ are definable, $ \RM ( A ) $ is finite and $ f : A \to B $ is a definable surjective map such that $ \RM \big( f ^ { - 1 } ( b ) \big) = k $ for all $ b \in B $. Show that $ \RM ( A ) \ge \RM ( B ) + k $. [Hint: Prove by induction on rank that $ \RM \big( f ^ { - 1 } ( X ) \big) \ge \RM ( X ) + k $ for all definable $ X \subseteq B $.]
>
> b) Suppose that $ G $ is an $ \omega $-stable group of finite Morley rank and $ H \le G $ is an infinite definable subgroup. Show that $ \RM ( G ) \ge \RM ( H ) + \RM ( G / H ) $. In particular, $ \RM ( G ) > \RM ( G / H ) $.
>
> c ) Show that b) is not true for all $ \omega $-stable groups. [Hint: Let $ K $ be a differentially closed field and consider the derivation $ \delta : K \to K $.]

First of all, doesn't $ H $ have to be a normal subgroup of $ G $ so that $ G / H $ can be defined? Or does $ G / H $ mean something other than the quotient group? And lastly, as far as I know, Morley rank is defined on formulas and definable subsets of the [monster] model. So, how is the question about the Morley rank of $ G / H $, which consists of cosets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The algebra question:* When $H$ is an arbitrary subgroup of $G$, $G/H$ often denotes the set of left cosets of $H$, $\{gH\mid g\in G\}$. When $H$ fails to be normal, we can't equip $G/H$ with a natural group structure, but we can equip it with the structure of a $G$-set: the action of $G$ on $G/H$ is the obvious one $g'\bullet (gH)= g'gH$.

*The model theory question:* While $G/H$ is not a definable set in $G$, it is an *imaginary* definable set, i.e. a definable set in $G^{\text{eq}}$. Precisely, suppose $\varphi_H(x)$ is the formula defining $H$. Then there is a definable equivalence relation $E(x,y)$ on $G$, given by $\exists z\, (\varphi_H(z)\land xz = y$), and the equivalence classes mod $E$ are exactly the left cosets of $H$. Since Morley rank makes sense in $G^{\text{eq}}$, we can define $\mathrm{RM}(G/H)$ to be the Morley rank of the set of $E$-classes in $G^{\text{eq}}$.

Comment: I think I understand it now, but I still have a problem using part a) to prove b). It's somehow obvious that I should take $ A = G $, $ B = G / H $ and $ f = x \mapsto x H $. But what should I take as $ \mathbb M $? The first choice seems to be $ G ^ { \mathrm { eq } } $, and I think $ \omega $-stability of $ G $ yields $ \omega $-stability of $ G ^ { \mathrm { eq } } $ (right?). But if $ G ^ { \mathrm { eq } } $ is taken to be the monster model, it must be $ \aleph _ 0 $-saturated, as morley rank is defined in such models. How can I prove this condition? Or should I do something else?

Comment: @MohsenShahriari You can work in $\mathbb{G}^{eq}$, where $\mathbb{G}$ is a saturated elementary extension of $G$. In general, if $M$ is any structure, and $X$ is a definable subset of $M$, you can define $\text{RM}(X)$ to be the Morley rank of $X(\mathbb{M})$, where $\mathbb{M}$ is an $\aleph_0$-saturated elementary extension of $M$, and this is independent of the choice of $\mathbb{M}$. And yes, passing to $M^{eq}$ preserves $\omega$-stability

Comment: But if we work in $ \mathbb G ^ { \mathrm { eq } } $, will $ G $ be a definable subset, so that we can take $ A = G $?

Comment: You don't want to take $A=G$. The Morley rank of $G$ is the Morley rank of the formula $x=x$ which defines the whole domain of $G$, so it's computed by looking at the whole domain of $\mathbb{G}$.